# Updating Map Layout Pathways in ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a map which has two insets which looks like this:

[image]

The first map frame is in the upper left and the second is all of the background.  Using my exact same map layout as shown here I just want to update the pathway of a layer.

For example, I am just trying to update one layer here, and that is the raster of Alaska shown in the upper left.

I am trying to update the layer like this:

```
#load in the map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("my_project")

#get the first map frame
one = aprx.listMaps[0]

#get the layers in that frame
one_layers = one.listLayers()

#list all the pathways
for layer in one_layers:

     print (layer.dataSource)
```

This returns four layers which are the correct pathways for that map frame.

I want to replace one called `"/Users/user/Fall/sen.tif"` to `"/Users/user/Spring/sen.tif"`

I am trying to do this like so:

```
aprx.updateConnectionProperties("/Users/user/Fall/sen.tif", "/Users/user/Spring/sen.tif")

#save new layout
aprx.saveACopy("/Users/user/new_map.aprx")
```

I have also tried:

`one_layers[2].updateConnectionProperties("/Users/user/Fall/sen.tif", "/Users/user/Spring/sen.tif")`

where [2] is the layer location I want to replace but it is the same outcome.

but when I load the new map the layer was not updated.  My desired output is an updated layer with the same symbology as before applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateConnectionProperties` function works on the following objects: ArcGISProject, Layer, LayerFile, Map, and Table classes.

It looks like you are trying to run it on individual files, eg. the *.tif images.

Try removing the `"/sen.tif"` from your code:

```
aprx.updateConnectionProperties("/Users/user/Fall/sen.tif", "/Users/user/Spring/sen.tif")
```

becomes

```
aprx.updateConnectionProperties("/Users/user/Fall", "/Users/user/Spring")
```

Comment: That still didn't work, but there are numerous tif files in both `/Users/user/Fall` and `/Users/user/Spring`

Comment: So the function doesn't work on file directories/folders...maybe copy the *tif files into respective Feature Datasets inside  a file geodatabase, and then try the function. Also,

Comment: Also, this --->  #save new layout
aprx.saveACopy("/Users/user/new_map.aprx")  dosnt't save a new layout; it saves a new ArcGIS Pro project...

Comment: Anyway, something like this might work: import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'C:\Projects\MyProject\my_project.aprx')
aprx.updateConnectionProperties(r'C:\Projects\MyProject\Fall.gdb',
                                r'C:\Projects\MyProject\Spring.gdb')
aprx.saveACopy(r'C:\Projects\MyProject\my_project_copy.aprx')
del aprx

Comment: creating respective fgdbs for each set of *.tifs, then change path to each fgdb...